# Appropriate usage of the word "adverse"

Tags: word-usage

I have a problem with using the word "adverse". Is this sentence correct?

> My father was adverse me to become a teacher

Comment: I think you mean [*averse*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/averse): My father was **averse to me becoming** a teacher.

Comment: Can you clarify your sentence further, and perhaps give more context? 

At the moment, the word 'adverse' doesn't really make sense in this context. Is it possible that the word might be 'averse', which describes a feeling of opposition, and would make more sense within the context of the sentence.

Comment: *Adverse* doesn't fit in here.

Comment: I think you mean "averse" (not "adverse").

Answer (score 1):

> I have a problem with using the word "adverse".

A person cannot be *adverse*.  The typical phrase with *adverse* is "adverse effect" meaning an effect that prevents success.

As @Mick and others in the comments say, *averse* is likely what you mean, and a person can definitely be *averse to* things.

You can't put an object pronoun right after {to be} + {adjective}, it looks like you are trying to use {adjective} as a transitive verb and it doesn't make sense.  In this case it almost looks like you're trying to say *advise* which is transitive but means something different entirely.